# How can i call java script function(in .cs) in the OnClientClick of the link button?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, linkbutton

I write script like this in my **.cs** file :

```
 StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();
 script.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> function submitform(){");
 script.Append(" document.forms['" + ((HtmlGenericControl)frm).Attributes["id"] + "'].submit();} </");
 script.Append("script>");
```

---

How can i call this function in the `OnClientClick` of my link button ?

```
LinkButton hl_process = new LinkButton();
hl_process.OnClientClick = ""
```

---

## Edit1:

```
protected Control CreateCommForm()
{
    HtmlGenericControl frm = new HtmlGenericControl("form");
    frm.Attributes.Add("id", "sal");
    frm.Attributes.Add("method", "post");
    frm.Attributes.Add("action", "https://------");
    /////////////////////////////////////////
    HtmlGenericControl hdn_sal_a = new HtmlGenericControl("input");
    hdn_sal_a.Attributes.Add("id", "hdn_sal_a");
    hdn_sal_a.Attributes.Add("name", "hdn_sal_a");
    hdn_sal_a.Attributes.Add("type", "hidden");
    hdn_sal_a.Attributes.Add("value", Session["emp_num"].ToString());
    /////////////////////////////////////////
    HtmlGenericControl hdn_sal_b = new HtmlGenericControl("input");
    hdn_sal_b.Attributes.Add("id", "hdn_sal_b");
    hdn_sal_b.Attributes.Add("name", "hdn_sal_b");
    hdn_sal_b.Attributes.Add("type", "hidden");
    hdn_sal_b.Attributes.Add("value", Session["user_name"].ToString());

    frm.Controls.Add(hdn_sal_a);
    frm.Controls.Add(hdn_sal_b);

    column1.Controls.Add(frm);
    return frm;

}
```

Comment: Looks like a classic case of **bad** _separate of concerns_...

Comment: Why the server handles the client side scripts?

Comment: i create forms according to some params in run time .then i need to submit each form in the `onclient click` of the link button created in the run time

Comment: O.k. after the edit... move **all** the HTML part to the ASPX file, it's place isn't in the **.cs** files

Comment: The Visual part your application shouldn't be affected if you move your app to `java` or `ruby`. that's what `separate of concerns` is.

Comment: hmmmm , i need to create these forms in runtime dynamically , because i don't want to add form every time i add a new process .

Comment: You can create forms and any other element in _runtime_ with `javascript`, this is how `C#-asp.net` does it behind the scenes...

Comment: later i will edit this method to allow to create forms with ids, actions and hidden field values come from the db.

Comment: then how to create forms with hidden fields in dynamically with javascript according to data comes from the db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery to bind to the click event instead of doing this on the server side:

```
<a href="#" class="blah">Submit Me</a>
```

then in javascript something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.blah').click(function() {
   document.forms[0].submit();
});
</script>
```

Edit:

While you can generate UI elements with codebehind it's not quite the asp.net way. Use repeaters if you must repeat the generation of controls. Actually, creating multiple forms is not the asp.net way either, as it assumes only one form running at the server context and everything else binds to an event on submission. Anyways, it seems you're still learning asp.net and probably coming form PHP or something similar.

To accommodate your request, I'd advice to stay away from from generating JS on the server side. Give different class names to your forms and use the same method above. You don't need a `LinkButton` to submit the form, a simple anchor `<a>` fits the bill.

You can use the `ClientID` property (if you don't use classes), but you must first attach the parent control to the page for the algorithm to kick in.

So, your code would be something like:

```
protected Control CreateCommForm()
{
   ...
   column1.Controls.Add(frm);   

   HtmlGenericControl a = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
   a.Attributes["onclick"] = "$('#" + frm.ClientID + "').submit();";
   a.InnerText = "Submit me";
   frm.Controls.Add(a);
   return frm;
}
```

The alternative way (better separation of concerns)

```
protected Control CreateCommForm()
{
   ...
   column1.Controls.Add(frm);   

   HtmlGenericControl a = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
   a.Attributes["class"] = "submitter";
   a.InnerText = "Submit me";
   frm.Controls.Add(a);
   return frm;
}
```

And in javascript we find the parent form and submit it (this can be in a static js file):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.submitter').click(function( 
  $(this).parents('form').submit();
));
</script>
```

Comment: there are more than form each form created in run time i wanna to submit with specific link button created in run time

Comment: can i use your first update in the case i create my forms like i do in my method ??

Comment: i wanna the link out side the form because it 's the state

Comment: It depends where you are creating the link and how it's being attached to the page. If it's in aspx, use gdoron's code above. If it's in code behind use the CreateCommForm().ClientID to get the client id.

Comment: if the link is out side the form and i add class attribute to the form and the link giving them the same value to make the link submit the related form how to do this please.

Comment: ` a.Attributes["class"] ="a";`
` frm.Attributes.Add("class", "a");`

Comment: Ah, then you can simply do: `$.grep($('.a'), function(n,i) { return n.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'form'; }).first().submit()` to filter out the form with the same class.

Comment: Thanks a lot you help me to fix my problem , one more thing , i wanna to make the link open in a new window . i do the following but  in vain.
 `a.Attributes["target"] = "_blank";`

Comment: You cannot submit a form to a new window. But you can open the window first, then submit the form.

Comment: How can i do this : i use this code :

`HtmlGenericControl a = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
   a.Attributes["onclick"] = "$('#" + frm.ClientID + "').submit();";
   a.InnerText = "Submit me";`

Comment: thanks a lot , i fixed it just by
`frm.Attributes.Add("target", "_blank");` for the form

Answer (score 2):

*separate the concerns* The Visual part your application shouldn't be affected if you move your app to `java` or `ruby`. that's what `separate of concerns` is.

write the client script in the client, not in the **cs** file:

```
$('#<%= hl_process.ClientID %>').click(function(){
     ...
     $('#formId').submit();
     // if the button inside the form:
     this.form.submit(); // HTML5
     // Or:
     $(this).closest('form').submit(); 
     // if the button not inside the form :
     var class = $(this).attr('class');
     $('form.' + class).submit();
});
```

Comment: there are more than form  each form created in run time i wanna to submit with specific link button created in run time

Comment: no the button is n't in the form it is a link button out the form

Comment: @just_name. So give the same class to the button and to form. and select it with it, see my update

Comment: @just_name. I think you should open a new question about how separate the concerns with `DB` involved. This question is targeting too wide issue.

Comment: I will explain more my case :

I have a portal i need to send some data to the web sites(processes) in this portal . the processes created dynamically . so i decide to send them in hidden fields with some security levels . form for each web site(process) , each form has id, action and hidden fields values comes from the db . i create it dynamically .

Comment: @just_name. It can done with `ajax`. But please open a new thread with all the relevant code and explanations. Good Luck.